# Regexp: excluding a word but including non-standard punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to find strings that contain words in a particular order, allowing non-standard characters in between the words but excluding a particular word or symbol.

I'm using javascript's replace function to find all instances and put into an array.

So, I want `select...from`, with anything except 'from' in between the words. Or I can separate `select...from` from `select...from (`, as long as I exclude nesting. I think the answer is the same for both, i.e. how do I write: *find x and not y* within the same regexp?

From the internet, I feel this should work: `/\bselect\b^(?!from).*\bfrom\b/gi` but this finds no matches.

This works to find all `select...from`: `/\bselect\b[0-9a-zA-Z@\(\)\[\]\s\.\*,%_+-]*?\bfrom\b/gi` but modifying it to exclude the parenthesis "(" at the end prevents any matches: `/\bselect\b[0-9a-zA-Z@\(\)\[\]\s\.\*,%_+-]*?\bfrom\b\s*^\(/gi`

Can anyone tell me how to exclude words and symbols within this regexp?

Many thanks
Emma

**Edit: partial string input:**

```
left outer join [stage].[db].[table14] o on p.Project_id = o.project_id

left outer join
(
select
     different_id
    ,sum(costs) - ( sum(brushes) + sum(carpets) + sum(fabric) + sum(other) + sum(chairs)+ sum(apples) ) as overallNumber
    from 
    (
    select ace from [stage].db.[table18] J
```

**Javascript:**

```
sequel = stringInputAsAbove;    
var tst = sequel.replace(/\bselect\b[\s\S]*?\bfrom\b/gi, function(a,b) { console.log('match: '+a); selects.push(b); return a; });
console.log(selects);
```

Console.log(selects) should print an array of numbers, where each number is the starting character of a `select...from`. This works for the second regexp I gave in my info, printing: [95, 251]. Your \s\S variation does the same, @stribizhev.

The first example `^(?!from).*` should do likewise but returns [].

The third example `\s*^\(` should return 251 only but returns []. However I have just noticed that the positive expression `\s*\(` does give 95, so some progress! It's the negatives I'm getting wrong.

Comment: What about `/\bselect\b[\s\S]*?\bfrom\b/gi`?

Comment: Without any input strings to test against, I do not know if I should post my suggestion or not :) Please let me know if you really have strings with newline symbols and that you just need to match the leftmost "from", not the rightmost "select".

Comment: @stribizhev - thanks for your comment. The SQL strings will all be different. I don't have any \n symbols but the code is on a new line, and deleting these to bring "from" on a line with "select" has solved some problems (possibly with code other than that posted - i have tried many, many variations). I'll post up some SQL strings. thanks

Comment: Please post example strings, and also specify the expected output.

Comment: How do you want to handle `select fromage from french_cheeses`?

Comment: Parsing SQL with regexp suffers from the same problem as parsing any other language with regexp: it probably won't work very well and if it does it will be very painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\bselect\b^(?!from).*\bfrom\b` regex doesn't work as expected because:

1. `^` means here beginning of a line, not negation of next part, so
   the `\bselect\b^` means, `select` word followed by beginning of a
   line. After removal of `^` regex start to match something
   ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/7)) but it is still invalid.
2. in multiline text `.*` without modification will not match new line,
   so regex will match only `select...from` in single lines, but if you
   change it for `(.|\n)*` (as a simple example) it will [match
   multiline](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/8), but still invalid
3. the `*` is greede quantifire, so it will match as much a possible,
   but if you use reluctant quantifire `*?`, regex will match to first
   occurance of `from` word, and int will start to return [relativly
   correct result](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/9).
4. `\bselect\b(?!from)` means match separate `select` word which is not
   directly followed by separate `from` word, so it would be
   `selectfrom` somehow composed of separate words (because
   `select\bfrom`) so `(?!from)` doesn't work and it is [redundant](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/10)

In effect you will get regex very similar to what Stribizhev gave you: `\bselect\b(.|\n)*?\bfrom\b`

In third expression you meke same mistake: `\bselect\b[0-9a-zA-Z@\(\)\[\]\s\.\*,%_+-]*?\bfrom\b\s*^\(` using `^` as (I assume) a negation, not beginning of a line. Remove `^` and you will again get relativly valid [result](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/11) (match from `select` through `from` to closing parathesis `)` ).

Your second regex works similar to `\bselect\b(.|\n)*?\bfrom\b` or `\bselect\b[\s\S]*?\bfrom\b`.

I wrote "relativly valid result", as I also think, that parsing SQL with regex could be very camplicated, so I am not sure if it will work in every case.

---

You can also try to use positive lookahead to match just position in text, like:

```
(?=\bselect\b(?:.|\n)*?\bfrom\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD4xO0/12) - the `()` was added to regex just to return beginning index of match in groups, so it would be easier to check it validity

---

### Negation in regex

We use `^` as negation in character class, for example `[^a-z]` means match anything but not letter, so it will match number, symbol, whitespace, etc, but not letter from range `a` to `z` ([Look here](https://regex101.com/r/dO0fX3/1)). But this negation is on a level of single character. I you use `[^from]` it will prevent regex from matching characters `f`,`r`,`o` and `m` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO0fX3/2)). Also the `[^from]{4}` will avoid matching `from` but also `form`, `morf`, [etc](https://regex101.com/r/dO0fX3/3).

To exlude the whole word from matching by regex, you need to use negative look ahead, like `(?!from)`, which will [fail to match](https://regex101.com/r/eV4rC7/1), if there will be chosen word `from` fallowing given position. To avoid matching whole line containing `from` you could use `^(?!.*from.*).+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV4rC7/2)).

However in your case, you don't need to use this construction, because if you replace greedy quantifire `.*\bfrom` with `.*?\bfrom` it will match to first occurance of this word. Whats more it would couse problems. Take a look on [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/lW9vU7/3), it will not match anything because `(?![\s\S]*from[\s\S]*)` is not restricted by anything, so it will match only if there is no `from` after `select`, but we want to match also `from`! in effect this regex try to match and exclude `from` at once, and fail. so the `(?!.*word.*)` construction works much better to exclude matching line with given word.

So what to do if we don't what to match a word in a fragment of a match? I think `select\b([^f]|f(?!rom))*?\bfrom\b` is a [good solution](https://regex101.com/r/sY4fW0/1). With `([^f]|f(?!rom))*?` it will match everything between `select` and `from`, but will not exclude `from`.

But if you would like to match only `select...from` not followed by `(` then it is good idea to use `(?!\()` like. But in your regex (multiline, use of `(.|\n)*?` or `[\s\S]*?` it will cause to [match](https://regex101.com/r/lW9vU7/1) up to next `select...from` part, because reluctant quantifire will chenge a plece where it need to match to make whole regex . In my opinion, good solution would be to use again:

```
select\b([^f]|f(?!rom))*?\bfrom\b(?!\s*?\()
```

which will not overlap additional `select..from` and will not match if there is `\(` after `select...from` - [check it here](https://regex101.com/r/sY4fW0/2)

Comment: Thanks for this. The regex101 link is also amazing - I didn't know about that site. Can you tell me: how do I make a negation using ^ ? Do I need brackets or something. Your regex works perfectly to find select...from and the explanations are useful - but I still don't know how to create the negative criterion. I.e. select...from without a from in the middle. Or select...from without a following '('. thanks for any help.